# Resolve PowerShell Function Parameter Values Among Parameters

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm trying to figure out how to force the PowerShell runtime to parse a string in expression mode when passing a parameter that includes another parameter's value to a function. For example, I want to pass two parameters to a function with the second parameter using the first parameter's value. I know I need to have the parser evaluate the second parameter value in expression mode but the output doesn't seem to resolve the first parameter's value.

PowerShell Command #1
This example works as desired and proves the command is evaluated in expression mode when using a sub-expression around 2 + 2

```
& { param($test1,$test2); $test1; $test2 } "foo" "Test 1 value: $(2 + 2)"
```

Output

```
foo
Test 1 value: 4
```

PowerShell Command #2
Now when I try the same things to have parameter two ($test2) reference the value for parameter one ($test1), the expression doesn't seem to be evaluated or at least the value for $test1 is blank or null.

```
& { param($test1,$test2); $test1; $test2 } "foo" "Test 1 value: $($test1)"
```

Output

```
foo
Test 1 value:
```

Note how the Test 1 value is blank when I think it should be "foo", the value passed in the $test1 parameter. What am I missing about parameter scope in a PowerShell function? Why is the $test1 value not available to be referenced in the expression passed as the value for $test2? Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses and that helps clarify some things. Ultimately, I want to pass parameters to a script from a database. The parameter values include references to other PowerShell parameters and they can't be resolved until the script runs. I'm running a PowerShell runspace in IIS and I couldn't figure out how to force the parser to evaluate an expression using the standard "" characters.

Alas, I found the $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString() function in PowerShell that does exactly what I need. This function actually is executed under the covers by the "" characters as documented at http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/archive/2009/03/30/chapter-12-command-discovery-and-scriptblocks.aspx#executioncontext.

It takes a little extra work to do what I want but I was able to use the following pattern to resolve the values in the script. This forces the parser to re-evaluate $test2 in expression mode and perform the variable subsitution, resulting in a string that includes the proper variable values.

```
$test2 = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($test2)
```

Thanks again for the comments and guidance!

Comment: it's good you found that, I guess you are executing $test afterwards with a `& $test2`? btw, if it's the answer you should mark it, the tick on the left does the job. :-)

Comment: I'm not actually executing a command using the & $test2 syntax afterward. Instead, the variable values are parsed and substituted in the original string to be used further down in the script. The key is forcing the parser to re-evaluate the variables using the ExpandString function in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the "expression" is evaluated outside the scriptblock, before even passing the arguments to the scriptblock.

So something like:

```
$test1 = 4
& { param($test1,$test2); $test1; $test2 } "foo" "Test 1 value: $($test1)"
```

will give the output:

```
foo
Test 1 value: 4
```

Workarounds:

```
& { param($test1,$test2); $test1; & $test2 } "foo" {"Test 1 value: $test1"}
```

But I suppose in the real situation, you wouldn't want to change the scriptblock ( or function etc. ) you are working with.

I would also question the need for this situation, as what you really want to do is this:

```
$test1 = "foo"
$test2 = "Test 1 value: $test1"
& { param($test1,$test2); $test1; $test2 } $test1 $test2
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround using the script block around the second parameter value. This does resolve the issue and force expression mode parsing.

Answer (score 0):

reminds me of schema\lisp! You can pass functions as parameters in that language - I don't know if you can pass a scriptblock as a parameter in PS though.

Anyway, does it matter what that you refer to the name of the variable?

If not and you just want to refer to the first variable (or the variable of your choice) you could do something like this:

```
 & { $args[0]; $args[1]; "Value of arg #$($args[1]): $($args[$($args[1])])"} "foo" "0"
```

works with other multiple variables:

```
& { $args[0]; $args[1]; "Value of arg #$($args[1]): $($args[$($args[1])])"} "foo" "3" 23 24 25 26
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas with the args collection. The names are important because there are internal variable references by parameter name in the script. I'm basically allowing parameters to interplay by using one param's value in other params.